# What's the logic behind or best practices with the pop and unshift methods?

Tags: ruby, arrays, methods

I can push an element into an array using `push`. If I make an array `a = ["alice", "bob"]`, `a[0]` = `"alice"` and `a[1]` = `"bob"`. I can push `"carl"` and it is at `a[2]`. But why would I want to `pop` it out and return it?

The `shift` method makes sense to me in that it removes the first indexed element and shifts the rest by one index. I can shift `"alice"` out of the array with `a.shift` and return `"alice"` with the effect that `"bob"` is now at `a[0]` instead of `a[1]`.

`unshift` would move things back to their original index though the references are all vaguely about prepending so that I can just arbitrarily unshift something that was never shifted.

I might want to operate on an array consistently, and so add new elements to one side, and remove them from the other. For instance, if the elements are being cycled through some process, it makes sense to work on and shift the first, and push any new elements to the end of the queue.

What advantage is there or in what scenario is it beneficial to prepend an element to an array (and alter the index of each element), or, on the other end, to pop the most recently added element?

Comment: Other than the fact that pop/push are faster it's really down to whether you want to add the element at the beginning or the end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need those methods to implement two different data structures: A stack and a queue.

A *queue* is like a queue in a supermarket. The one who is first in the list gets served. New customers wait at the end.

A *stack* is like a pile of papers on your desk. You can put more papers on that pile. If you take one of that paper you get the most recent one. Last in, first out principle.

And I think this is the reason why you cannot learn a computer language like a "normal" language. Because you need to know about the concepts behind it: common data structures, well-known algorithms, complex classes....

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I needed to give my study some more direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
But why would I want to pop it out and return it?
```

Here's an example of what you can do with pop():

```
dispatcher = {
  "+" => lambda {|x, y| x+y},
  "-" => lambda {|x, y| x-y},
  "*" => lambda {|x, y| x*y},
}

print "Enter two values followed by an operation(+, -, *): "
input_arr = gets.chomp.split()

func = dispatcher[input_arr.pop]  #Remove the operation from the array, so that you can...

input_arr = input_arr.map {|val| val.to_i}  #...call to_i() on the rest of the elements
result = func.call(*input_arr)
puts result

--output:--
$ ruby my_prog.rb 
Enter two values followed by an operation(+, -, *): 3 2 +
5
~/ruby_programs$ ruby my_prog.rb
Enter two values followed by an operation(+, -, *): 3 2 -
1
~/ruby_programs$ ruby my_prog.rb
Enter two values followed by an operation(+, -, *): 3 2 *
6
```

When you are learning a programming language, you are learning tricks.  You might not be able to envision how a trick is useful, but as you get more experience, you will think about a programming problem and hopefully the relevant tricks you know will spring to mind.

Also, you should know that pop() and shift() have different consequences.  It's much less efficient to shift() an element off the front of an array because all the other elements have to be moved over.  What if your array has 10 million elements in it?  Then pop()'ing an element off the end is easy, but shifting an element off the front is disastrous in terms of efficiency. The programming language Perl, which Ruby borrowed a lot of things from, creates arrays in such a way that pop() and shift() are equally efficient, but I don't believe ruby employs similar tactics.